# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid retrievedBook Id:1

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

While I trying delete Book entity with relations from database using this method

```
@Transactional
public void deleteBookById(Long id) {
   List<BookStatus> bookStatuses = bookStatusService.findBookStatusesByBookId(id);

   if (!bookStatuses.isEmpty()) {
        bookStatusService.deleteBookStatusesByBookId(id);
   }

   bookRepository.delete(findBookById(id));
}
```

I got an error
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid retrievedBook Id:1`
And here is more logs where you can see that this error appears exactly when I try do delete entity using hibernate

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid retrievedBook Id:1
   at kpi.diploma.ovcharenko.service.book.LibraryBookService.lambda$findBookById$0(LibraryBookService.java:128) ~[classes/:na]
   at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408) ~[na:na]
   at kpi.diploma.ovcharenko.service.book.LibraryBookService.findBookById(LibraryBookService.java:128) ~[classes/:na]
   at kpi.diploma.ovcharenko.service.book.LibraryBookService.deleteBookById(LibraryBookService.java:64) ~[classes/:na]
   at kpi.diploma.ovcharenko.service.book.LibraryBookService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6c90428f.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at kpi.diploma.ovcharenko.service.book.LibraryBookService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e887da09.deleteBookById(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
   at kpi.diploma.ovcharenko.controller.BookController.deleteBookById(BookController.java:155) ~[classes/:na]
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
```

But I have this entity in my database with such id, example below:
[image: my existed entity]
Here is my Book entity class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idbooks", insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "book_name")
    @NotBlank(message = "Book name is mandatory")
    private String bookName;

    @Column(name = "year")
    private int year;

    @Column(name = "author")
    private String author;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "section")
    private String section;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<BookStatus> statuses = new HashSet<>();

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<BookCategory> categories = new HashSet<>();

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<BookCard> bookCards = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE,
            })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "books_tags",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_tag_id")}
    )
    Set<BookTag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    public void addCategory(BookCategory category) {
        categories.add(category);
        category.setBook(this);
    }

    public void removeCategory(BookCategory category) {
        categories.remove(category);
        category.setBook(null);
    }

    public void setStatus(BookStatus status) {
        statuses.add(status);
        status.setBook(this);
    }

    public Book(@NotBlank(message = "Book name is mandatory") String bookName, int year, String author,
                int amount, String description) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.year = year;
        this.author = author;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Book book = (Book) o;
        return year == book.year && amount == book.amount && Objects.equals(id, book.id) && Objects.equals(bookName, book.bookName) && Objects.equals(author, book.author) && Objects.equals(description, book.description);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, bookName, year, author, amount, description);
    }
}
```

It's so strange error, but I even don't know what I can do to solve this problem.

Comment: `LibraryBookService.findBookById` please share code of this method, issue is there.

Comment: Here this method 
`@Override
    public Book findBookById(Long id) {
        return bookRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() ->IllegalArgumentException("Invalid retrievedBook Id:" + id));
    }`

Comment: Do you want to delete all book statuses when the parent book is deleted from the database?

Comment: Yes, and after it delete Book

Comment: could you try to remove this: columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)" and then drop the table 
 and save the entity again, and try to delete it this time (without specefying the column definition)

Comment: as you recommended I deleted  columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", then drop Book and BookStatus tables, create them again. But this is didn't help me(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future people who also may face such a problem. I decided that this problem appears because of Hibernate problem, because I solved it in such way.
Firstly a changed my Book entity class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idbooks", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "book_name")
    @NotBlank(message = "Book name is mandatory")
    private String bookName;

    @Column(name = "year")
    private int year;

    @Column(name = "author")
    private String author;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "section")
    private String section;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<BookStatus> statuses = new HashSet<>();

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<BookCategory> categories = new HashSet<>();

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<BookCard> bookCards = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE,
            })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "books_tags",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_tag_id")}
    )
    Set<BookTag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    public void addCategory(BookCategory category) {
        categories.add(category);
        category.setBook(this);
    }

    public void removeCategory(BookCategory category) {
        categories.remove(category);
        category.setBook(null);
    }

    public void addStatus(BookStatus status) {
        statuses.add(status);
        status.setBook(this);
    }

    public Book(@NotBlank(message = "Book name is mandatory") String bookName, int year, String author,
                int amount, String description) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.year = year;
        this.author = author;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

After that I change default Hibernate method deleteById() to this in my BookRepository interface

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM Book b WHERE b.id = :id")
void deleteBookById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

In my BookService method deleteBookId() I remove deleting BookStatus because BookStatuses deletes cascadly when my book successfully deleted. And add method that delete all book cards by book id

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteBookById(Long bookId) {
    bookCardService.deleteAllBookCardsByBookId(bookId);

    bookRepository.deleteBookById(bookId);
}
```

Here is deleteAllBookCardsByBookId in BookCard repository interface

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from BookCard bc where bc.book.id = :id")
void deleteBookCardsByBookId(Long id);
```

And after all this changes I solved my problem and successfully delete book entity.
I really hope that my solution to this problem in the future will be useful to anyone who encounters the same as me

Answer (score 0):

here:

```
   bookRepository.delete(findBookById(id));
```

you are trying to pass **findBookById(id)** (which is of type **Optional**) to the method delete, actually this method is waiting for a parameter of type **Long** and not **Optional**.

Try to delete the book by passing directly the id:

```
bookRepository.delete(id);
```

verify before that the id your are passing is of type Long.

Comment: Of course I tried to user default deleteById() method, like this:
`@Transactional
    public void deleteBookById(Long bookId) {
        List<BookStatus> bookStatuses = bookStatusService.findBookStatusesByBookId(bookId);

        if (!bookStatuses.isEmpty()) {
            bookStatusService.deleteBookStatusesByBookId(bookId);
        }

        bookRepository.deleteById(bookId);
    }`
But I got about the same error 
`org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class kpi.diploma.ovcharenko.entity.book.Book entity with id 1 exists!
`

Comment: And here is my debugger where you can see that id has Long type:
**bookId = {Long@12617}1**

Comment: I have some doubt that @Transactional annotation could cause those kinds of issues, could you try to manually commit your transaction before deleting the book so you could be sure that the book is already stored.

Comment: Ok, I will try it, but my book 100% is already stored, because I try do delete it and I saw I image of my database. Or I mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<BookStatus> bookStatuses = bookStatusService.findBookStatusesByBookId(id);

   if (!bookStatuses.isEmpty()) {
        bookStatusService.deleteBookStatusesByBookId(id);
   }

   bookRepository.delete(findBookById(id));
```

In your method above(`deleteBookById`), you are retriving list of `bookStatuses`  & if its non-empty, you are deleting it. Once it get deleted, you are again trying to delete it in last call `bookRepository.delete(findBookById(id));`.

May be this is your issue. Can you check if `bookStatuses.isEmpty()` condition is true & if deletion is happening prior to `bookRepository.delete(findBookById(id));` call?

Comment: If I correctly understand you, my book has 1 BookStatus, so condition is true, one BookStatus successfully deleted and after that my service try delete Book by id, but it throw an error

Comment: @OleksandrOvcharenko , ok, got it, you mean `bookStatusService.deleteBookStatusesByBookId(id);` deletes from other table.

Comment: Yes, my book has @OneToMany relation to the BookStatus entity, here is my service method and repository method that deletes BookStatus entities depending on Book Id
 `bookStatusRepository.deleteBookStatusesByBookId(bookId);`
 `void deleteBookStatusesByBookId(Long bookId);`

Comment: can you look at `cascade ` attribute if it is doing any harm while deleting your `@OneToMany` relation?

Comment: My Both entities(Book, BookStatus) annotated by CascadeType = ALL. It means that BookStatus will be deleted cascadly